# select audio context destination output

Tags: javascript

I need a solution to set an `<audio>` element as the destination of a decoded streamed audio. I want that the user can click the record button and record the audio until he release the button, then using websockets I will send the audio to the other users in the same room that can press the play button to listen to the received audio.

I've searched a bit on SO, I've found two solutions I've implemented to decode an ArrayBuffer sent from `MediaRecorder()`, but it will play automatically and I'm not able to assign the audio to an html element.

Here is my JS code to decode audio:

```
// socket.io listening for audio event
socket.on('audio', function(audio){
          console.log(audio);
// this part comes from a suggested solution to read the ArrayBuffer into an audio 
          console.log("now playing a sound, that starts with", new Uint8Array(audio.slice(0, 10)));
          var dest;
            audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audio, function (buffer){
                if (!buffer) {
                    console.error("failed to decode:", "buffer null");
                    return;
                }
                var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
                source.buffer = buffer;
                source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                //source.start(0);
// here is where I'm trying to pass the audio to the <audio> element
                dest = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
                console.log(dest.stream);

                var player = document.getElementById('audio-player');
                player.src = URL.createObjectURL(dest.stream.id);
                console.log("started...");

            }, function (error) {
                console.error("failed to decode:", error);
            });
        });
```

Here is the record button code I'm using, I want to change as I described in the question to record until it's released by the user.

```
        $('.audio-message').on("click",function(){
          console.log('clicked');
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true
          })
          .then(function(stream){
            var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.start();
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
              // chunks.push(e.data);
              console.log(e.data);
              socket.emit('audio', e.data);
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
              mediaRecorder.stop();
            }, 10000);
          });
        });
```

The ideal solution for me is to generate the audio element dynamically when the file is received from the users. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need the `audio` tag? Seems pretty redundant when you just could play it with the `Web Audio API`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, it's needed because it's an audio chat app, so if the audio will play automatically will create confusion for the user, it's also a privacy choice, nobody want that a provate audio can be heared from other peoples because it  play automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender side could send the data as `Blob` since `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` returns `BlobEvent` and  `URL.createObjectURL()` already takes `Blob` as an argument.
This is usually already the default `binaryType` of a [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). You can leave the sender code as is, but the receiving side can be simplified. (Assuming you simply forward the data from the server without changing it)

```
socket.on('audio', function(audio){
    console.log(audio);
    var player = document.getElementById('audio-player');
    player.src = URL.createObjectURL(audio);
    console.log("started...");

    }, function (error) {
         console.error("failed to decode:", error);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's the same solution I've adopted after some research. The `e.data` is an `ArrayBuffer`, I've created an array named `chunks` and then pushed the data inside it, on the receiving side I've then created the blob url.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to create a whatsapp like button to record the stream?